# Comparing values from several JS arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

**The facts:**

- I have several arrays (anywhere from 2 to dozens), all comprised of CSS classes.
- Every class in each array is namespaced with one of the following: `'alignment__'`, `'font__'`, `'leading__'`, `'size__'`, or `'tracking__'`.
- The values in the arrays will not usually be in the same order.
- The arrays will not always contain a value for each namespaced class.

**What I need:**

- If the value for each namespace is *the same* in every array, I need to return the `className` *without* the namespace.
- If the value for any namespace is *different* in any array, I need to return `false`.

**Example:**

Here is a small example of a collection of arrays I’ll be working with:

```
p1 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"];
p2 = ["size__18px", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408", "alignment__left"];
p3 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"];
p4 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px"];
```

This collection of arrays should return something like:

```
return {
    alignment: 'left',
    font: false,
    leading: false,
    size: '18px',
    tracking: false
}
```

Suggestions? Every angle I approach this from just seems slow and inefficient. I’m using lodash in this project, in case that simplifies things at all.

Comment: If you downvote the question, please leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Maybe post the code you've already attempted into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I threw together.

```
'use strict';
const originalArrays = [
  ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"],
  ["size__18px", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408", "alignment__left"],
  ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"],
  ["alignment__left", "size__18px"]
]
const countInArray = (array, what) => {
  lt count = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] === what) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};
const theFunction = (originalArrays) => {
  const flattenedArray = originalArrays.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
  let interimResults = [];
  let results = {};

  for(let item of flattenedArray) {
    if(countInArray(flattenedArray, item) === originalArrays.length) {
      if(interimResults.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        interimResults.push(item)
      }
    } else {
      results[item.split('__')[0]] = false;
    }
  }

  for(let result of interimResults) {
    let parts = result.split('__');
    results[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  }
  return results;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Find below a simple way to achieve that using lodash:

```
const u = require('lodash');

var p1 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"];
var p2 = ["size__18px", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408", "alignment__left"];
var p3 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"];
var p4 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px"];

// I will obtain the unique values from the arrays given using the `union` method:
var union = u.union(p1, p2, p3, p4)

// Then, I will create an array of unique values that are included in all given arrays.
var inter = u.intersection(p1, p2, p3, p4)

// Finally, you can use the `difference` method to obtain those unique values 
// that are not included in the `union` array.
var diff = u.difference(union, inter);
```

So, in the `inter` array you will have the classNames that have the same value in all of the array defined above (p1, p2, p3, p4) and the `diff` array will have all of the namespaces that were not included in each array.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this. If I understand your problem correctly the following could be one of the ways to solve this. I cannot say if this is optimal. I'll try to figure out a better way. But for now here's the code.

```
var functionWhichHasAccessToArrays() {
    var totalNoOfArrays = someNumber; // 2 or dozens

    function doAllArraysHaveSameValue(value) {
        return !!(_.every(arrayOfArrays, function(array) {
            return (-1 !== _.indexOf(array, value));
        }));
    }

    var result = {};
    _.each(arrayWithMaxLength, function(valueInArray){
        var keyValue = valueInArray.split('__');
        if (doAllArraysHaveSameValue(valueInArray)) {
           result[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
        } else {
            result[keyValue[0]] = false;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. Didn't come out as clean as I intended but it seems to get the job done.

```js
p1 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"];
p2 = ["size__18px", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408", "alignment__left"];
p3 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px", "leading__170", "tracking__0", "font__Operator--1408"];
p4 = ["alignment__left", "size__18px"];

var classes = [p1, p2, p3, p4],
    flat = classes.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev.concat(curr) }, []),
    unique = flat.reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
      return prev.indexOf(curr) == -1 ? prev.concat([curr]) : prev;
    }, []);

var result = {};

unique.forEach(function (style) {
  result[style.split('__')[0]] = classes.every(function (clss) {
    return clss.indexOf(style) !== -1;
  }) ? style.split('__')[1] : false;
})

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<body>
  <pre id="result">
  </pre>
</body>
```